# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error running pip install selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pip, installation, typeerror

I have a fresh installation for Python on my PC. To reproduce the issue, I open the command prompt and executed the command:

```
pip install selenium
```

I am seeing the following error:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

[image: error]

Comment: Please read why you [should not post screenshots of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+%27module%27+object+is+not+callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this fiexed it:

python -m pip install selenium --user

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

...implies that the program was unable to locate **pip.exe** with in your system.

From the image it is pretty clear that **Python** is installed in **`D:`** drive while you were trying to access it from **`C:`** drive.

Factually, it doesn't matters where ever you install Python within your system as long as you know where it is at and preferably the path is in your system path. You can use the following command to locate the *site packages* e.g. pip install

```
import site
print(site.getsitepackages())
```

However, to keep things simple you need to install Python in it's default location and add the path to the system path. Then you can easily run:

```
pip install selenium
```