# Do we need to install Selenium each time we open and execute a new project using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, module, webdriver

I have selenium installed and chrome driver in a python project, when i create a new project is says it can't recognize the selenium module.

Does this mean with each project I'll need to install selenium again?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, you don't need to install [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) for each project. The installation procedure is only once in a lifetime using either of the following commands through *command line interface*:

- Using *pip*:

  ```
  pip install selenium
  ```
- Using *pip3*:

  ```
  pip3 install selenium
  ```

---

### Upgrading pip

However, you would need to keep on [upgrading pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip) periodically:

- On [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) or [macos](/questions/tagged/macos):

  ```
  pip install -U pip
  ```
- On [windows](/questions/tagged/windows):

  ```
  python -m pip install -U pip
  ```
- Or

  ```
  C:\Users\username>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  Collecting pip
    Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/25/e52d3f31441505a5f3af41213346e5b6c221c9e086a166f3703d2ddaf940/pip-18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 1.3MB 544kB/s
  Installing collected packages: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 10.0.1
      Uninstalling pip-10.0.1:
        Successfully uninstalled pip-10.0.1
  Successfully installed pip-18.0
  ```

---

### Upgrading Selenium

As a mandatory measure you need to upgrade the *Selenium* bindings to keep in sync with the release of each [stable version](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) as follows:

```
C:\Users\username>pip install -U selenium
Collecting selenium
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/53/9cafbb616d20c7624ff31bcabd82e5cc9823206267664e68aa8acdde4629/selenium-3.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (898kB)
    100% |¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦¦| 901kB 380kB/s
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: urllib3 in c:\python\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.22)
Installing collected packages: selenium
  Found existing installation: selenium 3.12.0
    Uninstalling selenium-3.12.0:
      Successfully uninstalled selenium-3.12.0
Successfully installed selenium-3.14.0
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- [How to resolve Selenium with Python: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649959/how-to-resolve-selenium-with-python-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable/59654170#59654170)
- [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error with driver=webdriver(“C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243290/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-error-with-driver-webdriverc-pyth/51245550#51245550)
- [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error running pip install selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146236/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-error-running-pip-install-selenium/59146866#59146866)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize browser in selenium each time when you are trying to run your automation test.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
print(driver.title)
```

You dont need to install selenium everytime you just need to initialize browser session wwhen you are trying to run your test from differnt project.

Also use `pip to install` the selenium package.

Try below command to install selenium using pip command after installing python

```
pip install selenium
```

You will find your dependancies under `Python\Lib\site-packages`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need every time , you need use by giving path and locate to folder in your machine

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to. In cases where you create virtual environment for  each projects. It is better to have it install into the project virtual environment. This will save you a lot of stress debugging your code later in future.